# how to write an if statement in vimrc for checking subsequent character?

Tags: if-statement, vim

I want to check whether the next character is `}` or not and as a result do something.

In pseudo-code:

```
if true
  do <Esc>la
```

1. Initial situation:

   ```
   {some code|}

             ^(cursor is before the '}')
   ```
2. Press `}`
3. Result:

   ```
   {some code}|

              ^(cursor is after the '}')
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In insert mode, the following snippet should give you the character after the cursor:

```
getline(".")[col(".")-1]
```

which, in a conditional, would look like this:

```
if getline(".")[col(".")-1] == "}"
    " do something
else
    " do something else
endif
```

Since you are probably trying to write a custom mapping, using a function in an "expression mapping" seems best:

```
function! JumpOver(char)
    if getline(".")[col(".")-1] == a:char
        return "\<Right>"
    else
        return a:char
    endif
endfunction
inoremap <expr> } JumpOver('}')
```

[image: example]

Reference:

```
:help getline()
:help col()
:help :function
:help <expr>
```

Comment: thank you. by the way do know what is the map special key for ' and " ,  couldn't find them in :help map.

Comment: @ArminEbrahimi, I'm not sure what you are asking, here.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing for the double quotes and single quote (' ', " ") but i don't know how to map them(how to refer to them in vim). For instance we used { to say if { is pushed or ( to say if ( is pushed.

Comment: Well… `}` is `}` and `)` is `)`, so `'` is `'` and `"` is `"`.

Comment: The provided function is generic enough to [work with any printable character](https://i.imgur.com/OuynVv0.gif), `'` and `"` included.

Answer (score 0):

This works quite similar to romainl's solution, converting <kbd>}</kbd> to <kbd>→</kbd> in order to skip over an already present closing brace:

```
:imap <expr> } nr2char(screenchar(screenrow(),screencol()))=="}" ? "<Right>" : "}"
```